# Calling a C function from C++, "no matching function" error

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction

I've defined the following header file (in C), left out the function implementation since thise aren't needed:

```
#ifndef FFMPEG_MEDIAMETADATARETRIEVER_H_
#define FFMPEG_MEDIAMETADATARETRIEVER_H_

#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavutil/dict.h>

int setDataSource(AVFormatContext** pFormatCtx, const char* path);

#endif /*FFMPEG_MEDIAMETADATARETRIEVER_H_*/
```

In C++, I defined my second header file:

```
#ifndef MEDIAMETADATARETRIEVER_H
#define MEDIAMETADATARETRIEVER_H

using namespace std;

extern "C" {
  #include "ffmpeg_mediametadataretriever.h"
}

class MediaMetadataRetriever
{
public:
    MediaMetadataRetriever();
    ~MediaMetadataRetriever();
    int setDataSource(const char* dataSourceUrl);
};

#endif // MEDIAMETADATARETRIEVER_H
```

In, mediametadataretriever.cpp I defined the following function:

```
int MediaMetadataRetriever::setDataSource(
    const char *srcUrl)
{
    // should call C function
    AVFormatContext* pFormatCtx;
    return setDataSource(&pFormatCtx, srcUrl);
}
```

When I try to compile this (C++) project in Eclipse I get a "No matching function call..." error related to:

```
return setDataSource(&pFormatCtx, srcUrl);
```

If I comment out the call, the code compiles fine:

```
int MediaMetadataRetriever::setDataSource(
    const char *srcUrl)
{
    return 0;
}
```

This appears to be a linking issue, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`setDataSource` in that context is the name of the member function. To invoke the free function, try fully qualifying its name:

```
return ::setDataSource(&pFormatCtx, srcUrl);
//     ^^
```